# SDLMain.h for Xcode

Tags: sdl

Does any one know what CPS is as mentioned in SDLMain.h

```
23 /* Use this flag to determine whether we use CPS (docking) or not */
24 #define SDL_USE_CPS   1
25 #ifdef SDL_USE_CPS
```

I can't seem to find it searching the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil Hassey had some experience with [porting-galcon-fusion-to-the-mac-app-store](http://www.philhassey.com/blog/2011/02/11/porting-galcon-fusion-to-the-mac-app-store/#comments) that mentions the use of this flag as being undocumented.  I wasn't able to come across any other relevant information.  He essentially suggests just commenting it out, if his situation applies to yours.

Comment: Thank you for this link.  Good to know.  _"He found that SDL had an #ifdef in its SDLMain.m which enabled some undocumented APIs being used. By commenting out “#define SDL_USE_CPS” he was able to resubmit and avoid the rejection notice. Mike also mentioned that SDL 1.3 doesn’t have this issue, but it’s still in beta and somewhat incomplete."_ **From:[porting-galcon-fusion-to-the-mac-app-store](http://www.philhassey.com/blog/2011/02/11/porting-galcon-fusion-to-the-mac-app-store/#comments)